# How do I write the integral over all $x$ in $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, definite-integrals

If I have $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ I would write the integral over some region $\mathcal{R}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ like:

$$
\int_\mathcal{R}f(\mathbb{x})\mathrm{d}\mathbb{x}.
$$

What subscript should I use if I want to indicate the integral be taken over all $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: maybe from -infinite to  +infinity?

Comment: http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/chap9.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not $\mathbb{R}^n$? (which is indeed quite a common notation.)

Alternatively, don't put any subscript, and simply indicate in the text of your document that the integral is being taken over all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Is that the standard way to write it? Thought it looked a bit odd.

Comment: @Andrew: I think it's actually more common to skip the subscript entirely, and let text explain (or let the notation imply what is intended). For example, the text might say "*Let $m$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and consider the integral $\int f\,dm$*".